# Present a drive on a server as a NFS to other network devices

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, nfs

Is there a tool that would allow me to take a shared folder on a server running server 2008 and make it look like a NFS drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Services for NFS

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753302(WS.10).aspx